# Use of Firebase Admin SDK in firebase-database-dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-admin

I used firebase-database-dotnet in my .net client application with great success. Unfortunately it does not support the new Firebase Admin SDK and the use of app-secrets is unfortunately deprecated.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

does someone know how to use Firebase Admin SDK with firebase-database-dotnet?
Thank you

firebase-database-dotnet
https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There currently is no Firebase Admin SDK for .NET.

We occasionally (but not frequently) get this request. I suggest you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to add your vote.

Comment: Thx puf, I will do that! There are some third party firebase nuget packages for .net. Their downloads sum up to over 150k. so likely not everyone who wants it, requests it as well